# How to return all objects in a group to their original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

There was a problem, I can not return the object to its original state in any way.
I tried to do it through the cache into a variable:

```
private Transform Trans;
private void Start() {
    Trans = transform;
}
```

But then I realized that this is just a reference to the object and the values are the same and nothing comes out.

The idea came to clone an object:

```
private void Start() {
    Trans = transform;
    if (!Clone) {
        Clone = Instantiate(Trans.gameObject);
        Clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        Clone.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (Clone) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clone.childCount; ++i) {
            Transform Child = Clone.GetChild(i);
            string Name = Child.name;
            SaveTransforms.Add(Name, Child);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `SaveTransforms` is:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, Transform> SaveTransforms = new Dictionary<string, Transform>();
```

After trying to assign transformations, when I need to return all `GameObjects` to the starting position:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Transform> entry in SaveTransforms) {
    string Name = entry.Key;
    Transform OldTransform = entry.Value;
    for (int i = 0; i < Clone.childCount; ++i) {
        Transform Child = Trans.GetChild(i);
        if (Child.name.Equals(Name)) {
           Child.transform.position = OldTransform.position;
           Child.transform.rotation = OldTransform.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

But even here nothing comes of it, although the cloned object is added and its positions do not change when I change it in another, and when I do:

```
print(Child.transform.position);
print(Transform.position);
```

Produces the same values.
As if the clone is also a link.
Guys, did anyone encounter a similar problem?
Is there a way to copy it as everything was or return the positions to their initial values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Transform> entry in SaveTransforms) {
    string Name = entry.Key;
    Transform OldTransform = entry.Value;
    for (int i = 0; i < Clone.childCount; ++i) {
        Transform Child = Trans.GetChild(i);
        if (Child.name.Equals(Name)) {
           Child.localPosition = OldTransform.localPosition;
           Child.localRotation = OldTransform.localRotation;
        }
    }
}
```